# Can't hide the top and bottom lines in custom searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, searchbar, uisearchbartextfield

[image: image link: https://github.com/Tambanco/issueSearchBar/blob/main/issue_Lines.jpg]

I´ve tried to change background color inside class SearchBarView: UIView {}:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear
```

and tryed something like that inside MainViewController:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear
searchBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

but, unfortunately I still see this lines inside my custom searchBar.
How can I get rid of these lines?

My SearchBarView class:

```
class SearchBarView: UIView {
    lazy var searchBar = createSearchBar()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(searchBar)
        
        searchBar.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(32)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(34)
            make.width.equalTo(300)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

fileprivate extension SearchBarView {
    private func createSearchBar() -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.placeholder = "   Search"
        searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "MarkPro", size: 15)
        searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
        let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        let imageV = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as! UIImageView
        imageV.image = imageV.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        imageV.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "FF6E4E")
        return searchBar
    }
}
```

My MainViewController class:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    private var searchBarView: SearchBarView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSearchBarView()
    }
    private func setupSearchBarView() {
        searchBarView = SearchBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        view.addSubview(searchBarView)
        
        searchBarView.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
        searchBarView.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        searchBarView.searchBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        searchBarView.searchBar.searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true
        let directionalMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 24, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        searchBarView.searchBar.directionalLayoutMargins = directionalMargins
        
        searchBarView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(categoriesView.snp.bottom)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(60)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the top and bottom border lines on the textfield disappear (the dark gray ones), you will want to tweak the text field's border properties rather than the background colors. Try something like this:

```
searchBar.searchTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

or

```
searchBar.searchTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

and adapt it to fit how you've set up the relevant subviews in your custom search bar.

Comment: I've added your lines of code, but it didn't affect the result. But if I change the layer.backgroundColor to green, lines become green too. `searchBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor`

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Could you link a screenshot of what the debug view hierarchy looks like from the side?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not misunderstanding, you made a custom view that's supposed to look like a `UISearchBar`, correct? Assuming based on the title to your question

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I've created SearchBar class inherited from UIView `class SearchBarView: UIView {}`. Inside this class `lazy var searchBar = createSearchBar()`, constraint it. Declare property in MainViewController class `private var searchBarView: SearchBarView!`

Comment: and in viewDidLoad i called method `setupSearchBarView()`. This method:  `searchBarView = SearchBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        view.addSubview(searchBarView)`

Comment: and   `searchBarView.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
        searchBarView.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        searchBarView.searchBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        searchBarView.searchBar.searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true` and make constraints

Answer (score 0):

Set the searchBar background image to empty. This eliminates all background issues you may have such as unwanted lines. For more info reference Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624276-backgroundimage

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Yeap! It hid the UISearchBarBackground and left only the UISearchBarTextField.